# XMLHTTPRequest No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, xmlhttprequest

hope you'all feeling fine! Here is the problem, Im trying to make a simple xmlhttprequest using an url from localhost. The localhost is apache! xampp. Thanks! 
When I open the page it returns me: ***No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.***
I don't know how to fix the error, I have been trying some things but they didnt work for me, Im frustrated. Im using: OPERA and FIREFOX. 
Hope you can help me. 
Here is the code

```
var xhr;

function initXHR(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhr = new ActiveXOBject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //OLD BROWSERS
    }       
}

function makeRequest(url, methodAjax, readyFunction){
    xhr.onreadystatechange=readyFunction;
    xhr.open(ulr,methodAjax,true);
    xhr.send(null);
}

function donwloadFile(){
    initXHR();
    makeRequest("http://localhost/correcto.html","GET",readyFunction);  
}

function readyFunction(){
    if(peticionHTTP.readyState==4){ //DONE==The operation is complete.
        if(peticionHTTP.readyState==200){ //
            document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML=peticionHTTP.responseText;
        } else {
        document.getElementById("hi").innerHTML=peticionHTTP.statusText;
        }
    }
}

window.onload=donwloadFile();
```

Comment: your code is trying to making a request to different site, you have to enable CORS in the other site `http://localhost/correcto.html` in other words you're trying to access something outside your site which is blocked by browser for security

Comment: what is the address of your current site that you're browsing ?

Comment: Not exactly related, but `document.write` in an event handler will be the next step breaking your code.

Comment: @msoliman and how can enable cors? because I tried to do it but it doesnt work, thank u for you reply, I really appreciate it. The site is in al localhost server, http://localhost/correcto.html with apache! the file is in the file xampp/htdocs

Comment: @Teemu thank for u reply. I have changed it and and put a paragraph to change innerHTML but still doesnt work

Comment: https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html @TELPRO please add the header to your config and restart the server

Comment: also here is another help url, https://awesometoast.com/cors/ if it worked let me know to add or document a correct  answer otherwise leave a comment describing what is your current address